# OpenXML SpreadsheetML Sideways text

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, spreadsheetml

I'm trying to figure out how to get text to print sideways in a spreadsheet cell in OpenXML. I'm thinking it can be done somehow with the ExtendedProperties of the Cell class. here's what I've got.

```
  Cell cell = GetCell(worksheetPart.Worksheet, columnName, rowIndex);
  cell.DataType = CellValues.InlineString;
  cell.InlineString = new InlineString() { Text = new Text(textToInsert) };

  //fictitious method 
  cell.ExtendedAttributes.SpinSideways();
  worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save()
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059666/answer/submit?s=9219459d-a516-4000-9913-d6d5843fecb7 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Styles for cells are handled in the `CellFormats` section of an Excel document.  You can tell when a cell has a format when you look at the XML and see that the `s` attribute is set to an integer:

```
<x:c r="A1" s="1" t="s" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <x:v>0</x:v>
</x:c>
```

That attribute stands for the `StyleIndex` which is the `CellFormat` index in the `CellFormats` list that corresponds to the formatting for this cell.  Here is the XML of the `CellFormats` to hopefully make it a little clearer:

```
<x:cellXfs count="2" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" />
  <x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="1" borderId="1" xfId="0" />
</x:cellXfs>
```

In the above XML we have the `x:cellXfs` element which is the `CellFormats` element and it has two children of `x:xf` or `CellFormat` elements.  We know from the `StyleIndex` attribute that we want the first index (or second element) under the `CellFormats` element, which means we want this `CellFormat`:

```
<x:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="1" borderId="1" xfId="0" />
```

Now in order to have a cell's text be rotated you will need to control that via a `CellFormat`.  Here is the code you will need to use in order to create a CellFormat with 90 degree rotation:

```
public CellFormat GenerateCellFormat()
{
    CellFormat cellFormat1 = new CellFormat(){ NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, FontId = (UInt32Value)0U, FillId = (UInt32Value)0U, BorderId = (UInt32Value)0U, FormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, ApplyAlignment = true };
    Alignment alignment1 = new Alignment(){ TextRotation = (UInt32Value)90U };

    cellFormat1.Append(alignment1);
    return cellFormat1;
}
```

If you want the text to rotate at a different angle then just replace the 90U with whatever angle you want from -90 to 90.

Now you will need to insert that `CellFormat` into the `CellFormats` and then set that new index on the `StyleIndex` of the cell you want to have rotated:

```
Cell cell = GetCell(worksheetPart.Worksheet, columnName, rowIndex);
cell.StyleIndex = InsertCellFormat(workbookPart, GenerateCellFormat());

// Helper method to insert the cell format in the CellFormats
public static uint InsertCellFormat(WorkbookPart workbookPart, CellFormat cellFormat)
{
    CellFormats cellFormats = workbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Elements<CellFormats>().First();
    cellFormats.Append(cellFormat);
    return (uint)cellFormats.Count++;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying that  Elements<CellFormats> Sequence has no elements. Thoughts? @amurra

Comment: It means the CellFormats element doesn't exist and you will need to add it or use an Excel file that already has a CellFormat defined.

Comment: Forgot to tag you, how do I add the CellFormats Element? @amurra

Comment: Create a `new CellFormats()` object and add it to `workbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet`.

Comment: @amurra If you apply this code to multiple cells, won't that insert the cell format into the cellformats multiple times? If so, is there an easier way to insert the cell format one time and then apply it to multiple cells. individually?

Comment: @John The `InsertCellFormat` method returns the style index, so you insert it once and then just use the returned style index on additional cells.

Comment: @amurra When I execute return (uint)cellFormats.Count++ I get an error. "Error in implicit conversion. Cannot convert null object." and Count is null.

Comment: @John The first line in that method isn't returning a `CellFormats` object so you are probably getting a null pointer on the next line. That means your document doesn't have a CellsFormat object and you need to make sure one exists before using this method.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a style sheet and then you need to apply it to the cell.

Some important snippits:

For the stylesheet you will need to include:

```
Alignment align = new Alignment();
align.TextRotation.Value = 90;
CellFormat format =  CellFormat(){Alignment= align};
```

Then apply it to the cell

`cell.StyleIndex=INDEXOFYOURSTYLE;`

Resources:

Styling a spreadsheet:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisquon/archive/2009/11/30/stylizing-your-excel-worksheets-with-open-xml-2-0.aspx

MSDN- Alignment:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.alignment.aspx