# Rotate text in Excel using axapta X++

Tags: excel, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I need to display the output from Axapta in Excel in the following manner.
[image: Excel View]

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added the following method in my base Excel Class and am able to get the solution.

```
public void setCellProperty(int _r1, int _c1,int _r2, int _c2,
       int _orientation = 0,
       int _horizontalAlignment = 1,
       int _verticalAlignment = 1,
       boolean _wrapText = False,  
       boolean _addIndent = False,
       int     _indentLevel = 0,
       boolean _shrinkToFit = False,
       int     _readingOrder = 0, 
       boolean _mergeCells = False)
{
    COM cell1,cell2;
    str range;
    ;
    cell1        = null;
    cell2        = null;
    cell1 = worksheet.cells();
    this.variant2COM(cell1, cell1.item(_r1,_c1));
    cell2 = worksheet.cells();
    this.variant2COM(cell2, cell2.item(_r2,_c2));
    range   =strfmt("%1:%2",cell1.address(),cell2.address());
    cellRange   =worksheet.Range(range);
    cellRange.Mergecells(_mergeCells); 
    cellRange.IndentLevel(_indentLevel);
    cellRange.AddIndent(_addIndent);
    cellRange.Orientation(_orientation);
    cellRange.VerticalAlignment(_verticalAlignment);
    cellRange.HorizontalAlignment(_horizontalAlignment);
}
```

the variable `_orientation` decides the inclination, for the case above pass `orientation=90`

Answer (score 0):

See [this blog](http://www.dynamics-blog.com/2011/05/exporting-data-to-excel-from-axapta-x.html) on how to export to Excel.

"Rotate a text" is a text formatting option, [others](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?122610-Rotate-text-box&s=3708ee48768160b6fb17643d2ea93230) are [struggling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059666/how-to-rotate-text-in-excel-spreadsheet-cell-using-openxml-and-c-sharp) too.
It boils down to whether there is a Excel API, which do that.

Sorry, I can't help you futher.